# punctuating So and Then at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: punctuation, commas, writing-style

I am confused when to put a comma after "so" and after "then" at the start of a sentence.

> And then that's when you went to the store?
>
> Then at McDonald's you were only there for a year, year and a half?
>
> And she has to be able to get everything down.  So, if we talk over each other, it won't be clear.
>
> So, the last seven years you worked for Dollar General, correct?

Thank you!

Comment: It's a style choice, there's no hard and fast rule. If you feel like you'd naturally pause after so or then when speaking the sentence out loud,  put a comma in.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall I agree up to a point, but there are certain strings where there is more need for a comma. So she went out = So, she went out. So can you =/= So, can you(?) Then, she went out = Then she went out. Then Bill's married? But *Then, Bill's married?

Comment: So, basically, you're saying it's based on the spoken word and up to me as the editor?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, why do you mark "Then, Bill's married" with a *? Did you mean it's ungrammatical? If so, why? // Or if you meant the comma is really unacceptable there (why?), what about the comma when the following part has more surprise or shock, e.g. "Then, Bill has died!?"?

Comment: @Mr Reality At least in 'BrE', an introductory 'then' (and we're talking about the 'So', 'What you're saying then is that' sense) is never followed by a comma (contrast an introductory 'however').

Comment: I'd always consider an ellipsis essential to show the lengthy pause in your suggestion.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Nice, I didn't know that about BrE. But I didn't mean to suggest a lengthy pause in my example; in fact as I imagined the scenario the next word quite immediately follows the "then" -- does 'Then, Bill has *died*!?' convey the scenario any better to you? Also, would you seek to repunctuate this too with an ellipsis: "Then, Bill's dead!?"?

Comment: I'd only ever use zero punctuation or an ellipsis. The italics for emphasis are certainly an option. // I _can_ see myself using zero p, a comma, or an ellipsis with << And ... Bill is dead./!/? >>

Answer (score 4):

In each of the OP's listed examples involving *then* or *so*—

> And then that's when you went to the store?
>
> Then at McDonald's you were only there for a year, year and a half?
>
> So, if we talk over each other, it won't be clear.
>
> So, the last seven years you worked for Dollar General, correct?

—ElendilTheTall's comment (above) that including or omitting a comma after *then* or *so* is simply a style choice accurately describes the situation, because the sense of the sentence remains unchanged whether the comma is there or not.

But as Edwin Ashworth notes (in another comment), there are times when a sentence may mean different things, depending on whether the author includes or omits a comma after one of those words. In the case of *so*, this happens because the comma can indicate a difference between *so* in the sense of "as a result":

> So, we spent the night there.

and *so* in the sense of "in that particular way":

> So we spent the night there.

And in the case of *then*, it happens because the comma can indicate a difference between *then* in the sense of "it logically follows that":

> Then, we can eat.

and *then* in the sense of "at that time":

> Then we can eat.

In many instances, context will give a reader enough clues to figure out what sense of *then* or *so* the author intends, regardless of punctuation. But consistent use of suitable punctuation in potentially ambiguous situations involving these words will make the reader's job easier.